# navigation drawer close on empty space click

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I used slidingmenu for a while now i try to use navigation drawer. so i am not so comfortable with it.

the problem i am having is i want to close navigation drawer if user clicks on non-navigation drawer part.

|          |                     |
|          |                     |
|          |                     |
| x drawer |  ---  screen   ---- |
|          |                     |
|          |                     |
|          |                     |

if user clicks to screen part i want to close the drawer.

one of the problem is screen is an fragment which changes with the drawer item clicks.

```
   < android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


<include
    layout="@layout/app_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


<include
    layout="@layout/side_menu_layout"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#F2FFFFFF"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <include
            layout="@layout/sideview_layout"
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```